# xbuild dafny on Linux CS0518 error

Tags: dafny

I followed the instructions in the documentation to install Dafny on Linux, but when I use `xbuild dafny/Source/Dafny.sln` I get the following trace:

```
reference:/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll /warn:4
    CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Object' is not defined or imported
    CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.ValueType' is not defined or imported
    CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Attribute' is not defined or imported
    CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int32' is not defined or imported
    CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt32' is not defined or imported
```

I used the 64-bit version of Linux Mint 18.1. I get the same error in other Linux distributions as well (Fedora and Ubuntu).

The previous step (`xbuild Source/Boogie.sln` works fine)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following statement  `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5"` after `xbuild dafny/Source/Dafny.sln` and it was built successfully.